# Can't show text in a label with javaFX

Tags: javafx

Beginner for JavaFX, just the first try. I follow the tutorial step by step but don't know why it doesn't work after I add label. 
show in system it fine, but just not for label, and don't understand the console information.I had searched many and tried, still not work. 
Please help me Why this happen? and how to change it.

This is the main java.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
//import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().
 add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Main controller: 
    package application;

```
import java.awt.Label;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class mainController {

@FXML
private Label myMessage;
public void generateRandom(ActionEvent event){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int myrand = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(myrand));
    //System.out.println(Integer.toString(myrand));
}
}
```

FXML file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300" prefWidth="500" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.mainController">
<children>
  <Button layoutX="165.0" layoutY="174.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
onAction="#generateRandom" text="click me" />
  <Label fx:id="myMessage" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="121.0" 
prefWidth="284.0" />   //warning: You can not assign 'Label' to the controller field 'Label'
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here is the error I get when try to run this program.

```
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/code/eclipse/FXprac4/bin/application/main.fxml:12

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.Label field application.mainController.myMessage to javafx.scene.control.Label
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Main Controller class change lable java.awt.Label to javafx.scene.control.Label

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class mainController {
     @FXML
     private Label myMessage;
     public void generateRandom(ActionEvent event){
     Random rand = new Random();
     int myrand = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
     myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(myrand));
    //System.out.println(Integer.toString(myrand));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got this. it works. I am not familiar with java swing and this awt too. now get it~~still have lots to learn. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

in mainController  class you have imported import java.awt.Label; change this to
javafx.scene.control.Label then above error will go

Comment: Yeah！it works now! Thanks very very much……for hours searching.